# Function 'zmq_getsockopt' not found in [libzmq.so]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, zeromq

during run rake for rails application i got following error "Function 'zmq_getsockopt' not found in [libzmq.so]"

Anybody know how to resolve this? thanks

i use Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: From http://www.zeromq.org/blog:v2-0-7-released - "A zmq_getsockopt() function has been added." Perhaps you need to update ØMQ? (The actual lib, not just the gem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe try to update version of zmq gem.